# Filling enclosed space / air inside voxel models - any fast algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, 3d, modeling, wavefront

I've created a Voxelizer for .obj models which is working pretty well so far. However, it only turns the surface of the model into voxels and doesn't fill it up. And filling it up afterwards is very important for further exporting and optimization.

I was thinking about options to fill up the space but just couldn't put my finger on an efficient algorithm that does it.

This is what the inside of a "cat" looks like, exported as .obj again.
[image]

Is there any fast algorithms for detecting enclosed space within a voxel shape?

My voxels are being stored using either a

```
List<Voxel> //Voxel contains 4 integers for x,y,z,rgb OR
Map<int[], java.awt.Color>.
```

I would need an algorithm that works really efficiently with one of these.

Comment: How would you feel about approximative algorithms?  Does it have to work 100% if it is a closed space?  If not, you could send rays in 6 directions and for each voxel that each ray hits, perform a recursive check in each 5 directions (minus direction arrrived), etc.  Do this at recursion 4 with no rays that don't hit a voxel and you're fairly safe to assume that it is closed.

Comment: It does have to be absolutely accurate. What just came to my mind is maybe using a boolean[x][y][z] to represent air. That should actually be faster than using a set or a map. The thing is that every bit of air that indirectly connects to the bounding box is visible. So if I started looping at a point of the bounding box and expanded into all 6 directions around the voxel, you could achieve a fairly efficient result. I am still certain that there must be a better way...

Comment: It would probably be the fastest and easiest to have the voxelizer also fill the shape. I have no evidence, but a graphics rasterizer also fills shapes when rastering. It doesn't draw the stroke and then fill it in a second step.

Comment: I couldn't use graphics due to the fact that it would only affect the model on a 2d level. You would have to do extra loops inbetween every single new layer of voxels to see if the voxels below it were filled too or not.

Comment: If that was a response to my comment: I haven't said that you should use graphics. I just wanted to say that I have a feeling that filling the voxel model when you build it (as opposed to filling it afterwards) might be a better approach. The rastering was just illustration by way of a possibly related problem.

Answer (score 0):

here's the best approach I've come up with so far:
1) It starts from the assumption that you only have one volume: no separate polygon meshes. That's easy to check. If it doesn't hold true, extra steps would be required, but the process would still be the same.

2) Take any voxel in the grid which is not part of the shell voxels. ray trace it to the closest point on the mesh to figure out whether this is part of an inside or outside volume.

3) Recursively flood to all the neighbours which are not in the shell either, until there's no where to grow. When that happens you have recognized either the outside or inside of your mesh (depending on where you started).

4) finding the opposite volume is a simple subtraction operation: vol_2 = all_voxels - shell - vol_1. if vol_2 is empty, your shell is open and the flood operation permeated through the gaps.

Comment: or actually it might be closed, if the voxels are large enough that those of the shell fill the entire volume.